# Spring MVC Hibernate Application loading database table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I created a simple web application with SpringMVC and Hibernate. Everything works fine, my employees are added to database (using MySQL) but page don't show the list of them:

[image: that's how it look]

Also logger don't show any output message when I'm adding the object when it should show something like: "Employee add successfully, Employee details: ..."

Here's the page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Employee Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ccc;}
        .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}
        .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#f0f0f0;}
        .tg .tg-4eph{background-color:#f9f9f9}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Add a Employee
</h1>

<c:url var="addAction" value="/employee/add" ></c:url>

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="employee">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty employee.name}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="name">
                    <spring:message text="Name"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <c:if test="${!empty employee.name}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Employee"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty employee.name}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Employee"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<br>
<h3>List of Employees</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listEmployees}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Employee ID</th>
            <th width="120">Employee Name</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listEmployee}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td>${employee.id}</td>
                <td>${employee.name}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${employee.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${employee.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>

@Qualifier(value = "employeeDAO")
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee e) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(e);
        logger.info("Employee saved successfully, Employee details: " + e);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateEmployee(Employee e) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(e);
        logger.info("Employee updated successfully, Employee details: " + e);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("uncheked")
    @Override
    public List<Employee> listEmployee() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Employee> employeeList = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list();
        for (Employee e: employeeList){
            logger.info("Employee List::" + e);
        }
        return employeeList;

    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Employee e = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("Employee loaded successfully, Employee details: " + e);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeEmployee(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Employee e = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, new Integer(id));
        if(e != null){
            session.delete(e);
        }
        logger.info("Employee delete successfully, Employee details: " + e);
    }
}
```

My Service class:

```
@Service
@Qualifier(value = "employeeService")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{



    public EmployeeServiceImpl() {
    }

    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeDAO employeeDAO) {
        this.employeeDAO = employeeDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addEmployee(Employee e) {
        this.employeeDAO.addEmployee(e);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateEmployee(Employee e) {
        this.employeeDAO.updateEmployee(e);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> listEmployee() {
        return this.employeeDAO.listEmployee();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee getEmployeeById(int id) {
        return this.employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeEmployee(int id) {
        this.employeeDAO.removeEmployee(id);
    }

    public void setEmployeeDAO(EmployeeDAOImpl employeeDAO) {
        this.employeeDAO = employeeDAO;
    }
}
```

Here I create the mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Employee ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int employeeID;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Employee() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", employeeID=" + employeeID +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("employeeService")
    public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String employeeList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("listEmployee", this.employeeService.listEmployee());
        return "employee";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("person") Employee e){

        if (e.getEmployeeID() == 0){
            //new employee, add it
            this.employeeService.addEmployee(e);
        }else {
            //existing employee, call update
            this.employeeService.updateEmployee(e);
        }
        return "redirect:/employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "employees/remove/{id}")
    public String removeEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id){

        this.employeeService.removeEmployee(id);
        return "redirect:/employees";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees/edit{id}")
    public String editEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){

        model.addAttribute("employee", this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", this.employeeService.listEmployee());
        return "employee";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSP Page your checking condition listEmployees , but in Controller You have added as model attribute listEmployee. remove last character s from listEmployees in Jsp. It should work. Otherwise everything is fine.

```
 <c:if test="${!empty listEmployees}">
```

In Controller

```
model.addAttribute("listEmployee", this.employeeService.listEmployee());
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<c:forEach items="${listEmployee}" var="employee">
```

to

```
<c:forEach items="${listEmployees}" var="employee">
```